# Risks in processing a user-provided CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I upload a .csv file to server using ASP.NET FileUpload control and a button. How can I be sure if it is valid .csv file or not ? I mean hackers can write some **scripts inside file** or **they can convert abc.exe to abc.csv** and upload server. In second case, is there any way to execute abc.csv file and if it is, is there any solution to avoid from it?

I will read file and if it is in correct format, such as (name,age,birthplace), I will insert them to database. But hacker can write script like ('get all info','from','database'). 
I am using SQL Server and C#.
I had lots of research in internet but lots of posts are about images, not csv.

What are the risks of csv file while loading to server? How can I check if file has macro virus or something like that?
I hope I could explain my problem.
Please let me know your opinions.

```
  private void ReadCSVFile(string filepath)
    {
        receiverList = new List<ReceiverUser>();

        try
        {
            if (filepath == string.Empty)
                return;

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    SplitLine(line);
                }
            }

            #region row add test
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Mail", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(double));
            }

            DataRow NewRow;

            foreach (var item in receiverList)
            {
                NewRow = dt.NewRow();
                NewRow[0] = item.Name + " " + item.Surname;
                NewRow[1] = item.Mail;
                NewRow[2] = item.Amount;
                dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            }



            grdRec.DataSource = dt;
            grdRec.DataBind();

            #endregion
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

I read file using StreamReader. So if one of parameter of csv file includes a macro code, will it be executed directly? All I want is to know it actually.

Comment: You either read a file, or you execute it. Reading a file containing executable code does not execute the code. Whether a section of SQL in a file can be executed as SQL when you insert it, depends on how you create the SQL command in the first place. Also, a Macro virus (or EXIF exploit, or ...) only gets executed if a program (or library) that understands the format reads the file, has an interpreter for the actual format _and_ has an active vulnerability. So, in short: show your code.

Comment: Can you check my code please ?

Comment: There's no need to check `if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)`. When you first create a DataTable, there will be no columns anyways. Also, you can move `DataRow NewRow;` into the for loop so that it becomes `DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();` and your variable will be properly scoped. And lastly, do not have an empty catch block! If you can't do anything about the error, don't catch it. At least put some logging in there or an alert for the user that something went wrong.

Comment: yep, you are right, it is unnecessary, thanks @mason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every potential vulnerability you expose yourself to when dealing with uploaded files is determined by what you do with the file.

If you can let users upload files, which you store as-is for other users to download, then one user can upload a virus-infected executable that will ruin another user's system.

If you let users upload files to any hosted directory because they can provide a target filename and/or directory, they can upload a file that gets interpreted and/or executed by the web server by issuing a request to the file (.php, .aspx, ...). This way a malicious user can execute their code on your server, doing whatever their evil heart desires.

If you let users upload an image and then resize it through some library, then your server is vulnerable to the exploits that exist in that version of that library. A malicious user can then for example inject executable code in an EXIF tag if some image processor library is known to be vulnerable to that.

If you read a CSV file and want to insert its data into a database, then if you simply concatenate an SQL string using this user input, you're going to have yourself a [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/).

If you run an uploaded Word file through the Word application itself (with all security turned off), then Word Macros will be executed on your server. You also don't want that.

So it all comes down to user input sanitization.

Now for your actual question: you're reading user input into a DataTable, in order to later insert that into an SQL database. This is just fine, because a DataTable will do the proper sanitization before crafting the SQL. But don't take my word for it: for all we know, the DataTable has an exploit as well.

Comment: I will only accept CSV file. I will read file line by line and I think while reading file there is no problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the directions in the OWASP security topic about "Unrestricted file uploads" at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload.

In general, the best practice is to store the files with a internal and secure file name and store the real name in a database or another data source, associated to that file (*also, it helps when the file name contains characters that are incompatible with the target filesystem*).

If you don't need to track the file name of the uploaded file, then you can rename the file after uploading using another secure name.

Some Examples of distinct problems associated with file uploads are

> **Attacks on application platform**
>
> Upload .gif file to be resized - image library flaw exploited
>
> Upload huge files - file space denial of service
>
> Upload file using malicious path or name - overwrite a critical file
>
> Upload file containing personal data - other users access it
>
> Upload file containing "tags" - tags get executed as part of being
>   "included" in  a web page
>
> Upload .rar file to be scanned by antivirus - command executed on a
>   server  running the vulnerable antivirus software
>
> **Attacks on other systems**
>
> Upload .exe file into web tree - victims download trojaned executable
>
> Upload virus infected file - victims' machines infected
>
> Upload .html file containing script - victim experiences Cross-site
>   Scripting XSS)
>
> Upload .jpg file containing a Flash object - victim experiences
>   Cross-site Content Hijacking.
>
> Upload .rar file to be scanned by antivirus - command executed on a
>   client running the vulnerable antivirus software